# Gulpfile relative path to root

Tags: gulp

I want to approach my deploy folder from my gulpfile, I placed the gulpfile in the source folder so that it stays tidy. My current folder structure:

```
deploy
├── js
├── css
├── img
└── index.php
source
├── node_modules
├── base
├── structure
└── gulpfile.js
```

*Structure above is only a part of the full tree*

Part of gulpfile.js:

```
var path = {
    js: {
        src: [
            './source/_base/**/js/*.js',
            './source/_structure/**/js/*.js'
        ],
        deploy: [
            '../deploy/js/'
        ]
    },
// more below this line
```

The gulp task:

```
gulp.task('process-js', function(){
    gulp.src(path.js.src)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish))
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(plumber.stop())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.js.deploy));
});
```

When I execute my gulp task (which uses this deploy path) I get an error:
 `:Error: Invalid output folder at Gulp.dest`

Question:
**How can I use the gulpfile relative path to place files in the parent of the root folder.**

Comment: I don't know what you're passing to `gulp.dest()` but it's definitely not `'../deploy/js/'`.

Comment: Forgot to add that piece of code, edited the question

Comment: Well, there's your problem. `path.js.deploy` is an array, not a string.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, it is - of course - not possible to parse an array as a destination.